# What happened to my recovery partition after upgrading to Windows 8?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, formatting

After upgrading to Windows 8 Pro from Vista I noticed an unformatted Local Disk (M:). I think that this is my old Vista recovery partition (since I have nothing else connected) but I'm not sure. Is it safe to format that partition?

Here is what I get from Disk Management and Windows Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Open disk management and have a look.

Comment: If you can wait, why not contact tech suport at the PC manufacturer and ask them? the drive letter sounds strange (normally recovery prtitions don't have adroive letetr, but you might have added one somehow). Tech support ought to be able to tell you the size of the recovery parition; if this is differnt, then I say delete it.  In my experience, the recovery parition is always the first on the disk, before drive C:. What about this one?

Comment: @Moab ok, from disk Management, I can see my recovery partition (not appearing in explorer) and it has no drive letter. but the  drive M is a 24GB raw Healthy partition that i can't format.

Comment: post a screenshot

Comment: @Moab my system froze twice when i tried to format M:

Comment: @MimiEAM did it freeze or just take forever?

Comment: @Misha it freeze only when i try to format M: , I left it all night yesterday and nothing ihad to restart in the morning and it was still there

Comment: @MimiEAM Cut your losses and do a clean install.

Comment: ok, the recovery parition is the one before C, the 7.37gB.  If you can't format `M:`, use http://www.partition-tool.com/ to delete it, and expand `C:` to fill the space. Sicne `M:` has a drive letter, what happens when you try to open it, or do a `dir m:` ?

Comment: @MimiEAM what happens if you just try to delete it, no format?

Comment: @Mawg froze again, I think i'm just gonna do a clean install, this is just ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

1. From disk managment, it is clear that it is not your recovery partition as it is too large. Neverthless, if you don't suspect there is data in the partition, it should be safe to erase.
2. You should reinstall Windows because the partition scheme is not optimal, your system keeps crashing, and there are probably more things wrong.